# Prevent IE aborts Images With The Wrong Mime-Type

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, nginx, mime-types

I have a URL of an image

https://www.biossantibodies.com/image-raw/15986.jpg

If I copy that and paste it back on Chrome / Firefox / Safari

It will auto download and display, but IE doesn't do that.

This is what I see in IE:

[image]

Is it because of [IE aborts Images With The Wrong Mime-Type](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2609-internet-explorer-aborts-images-with-the-wrong-mime-type.htm) ?

---

I've tried adjusting adding these 2 lines in my `/etc/nginx/mime.types`

```
image/jpeg                            jpeg;
image/jpg                             jpg;
```

How do I bypass that ?

## Update

As suggested from **@Manngo**

I've tried

```
image/jpeg                            jpeg;
image/jpeg                            jpg;
```

and restart my NGINX Server

```
service nginx restart
nginx stop/waiting
nginx start/running, process 1755
```

Visit the URL (https://www.biossantibodies.com/image-raw/15986.jpg) in IE and still see the same result.

[image]

Comment: There is no `image/jpg`. Even with the `.jpg` extension, it should still be `image/jpeg`. Just change the second line to `image/jpeg  jpg;`

Comment: first `image/jpeg                            jpeg;`

Comment: second `image/jpeg                            jpg;` ???

Comment: Is that what you suggested ? OR 1 line is good enough ?

Comment: @Keep both. Basically, what you’re doing is matching file extensions to mime types. If you had an extension such as `'junk`, you could add that to the list too.

Comment: Sure will do, will report back the result of these lines

Comment: I’ve written that out as a proper answer.

Comment: I’m getting confused by your comments in my answer. Is your image a saved image, or is it generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `image/jpg`. Even with the `.jpg` extension, it should still be `image/jpeg`. Just change the second line as follows:

```
image/jpeg  jpeg;
image/jpeg  jpg;
```

Basically, what you’re doing is matching file extensions to mime types. If you had an extension such as `.junk`, you could add that to the list too, if that’s your idea of having a good time:

```
image/jpeg  junk;
```

Comment: I updated my post base on your answer. I wondered if what I am seeing is a default behavior of IE that can NOT be bypass. What do you think?

Comment: That’s weird. Can you try the following: (a) try with a different image on the same web site; (b) clear the cache; (c) try an image on a different web site; (d) try a different computer. I know that’s a lot, but it will help to narrow down the problem. (e) try a `png` on the same web site; (f) change the extenstion to `.jpeg`

Comment: Do you still have any otehr suggestions ?

Comment: @ihue What are the results of the six tests, especially the `png` one?

Comment: The images still display on chrome but not IE still. Unfortunately, I can not really test .png because We only deal with jpeg only. Other suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you change the file extension to `.jpeg`?

Comment: Final suggestions: open the image in an image editor and (a) save a copy as `png` — I know that you deal only with `jpeg`, but this is purely for trouble-shooting; (b) save a _copy_ as another `jpeg` — there may be issues with the original file itself.

Comment: See, the thing is, there is another team did the upload/move those uploaded images from a certain path from of a server to a certain path in another server. The migration script is happening daily in the morning daily. ... Thanks for tips, I will have to plan to test those. If you come up with suggestions, please kindly let me know..

Comment: Did you say another server? Does that mean the images are coming from another server?

Comment: I've tried to download an image from : http://biossantibodies.com/image-raw/14329, rename it to .png, and open it up in IE, I see : https://www.dropbox.com/s/oiqb8uvmooy7as5/img-002.png?dl=0

Comment: @ihue Don’t just rename it as `.png`, save it in the correct format. You can, however just rename to `.jpeg`.

Comment: It also appears that the image is not a saved image, but is generated. Is that the case?

Comment: I just test that IE can properly load any .png fine. If I will have to create a .png file from Photoshop or download 1 from Google, I should not have any problem displaying it. See : [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zz2jtp9y1ig8b8/img-003.png?dl=0)

Comment: I tried to check in IE > Network Tab > Filter by : images only > I saw the 200 ok. Like https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uj4bpq9n0go5x7/img-005.png?dl=0